# Trying to unzip a tgz in WSL but get ELF not found error

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, tar

I would like to unzip a .tgz file, but I get an `ELF not found error`. I am using Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.04 in WSL.

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image: ELF not found error]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Updated Short Answer:*

This *should* be fixed (see the Launchpad report below) in the latest Jammy updates.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
```

... and try again.

If not, please let me know (and more importantly, the Ubuntu team via a Launchpad report), but here's the old workaround ...

*Old Short answer:*

```
printf '#!/bin/sh\nexec /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/bin/gzip "$@"' | sudo tee /usr/local/bin/gzip
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gzip
```

*Explanation:*

This is currently a known issue with WSL1 and Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy), as well as some other recent distributions:

- [Launchpad report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gzip/+bug/1966849)
- [WSL GitHub report](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8219)

This renders Jammy fairly unusable under WSL1 since so many packages (including `apt`) utilize `gzip`.

Note (for others who search for this using different terms) that the error message when *creating* a tar is slightly different:

```
/bin/sh: 1: gzip: Exec format error
```

A similar (but not the same) occurred with `gzip` in Ubuntu Eoan a few years back.  Reference:

- [Launchpad report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gzip/+bug/1843479)
- [WSL GitHub report](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4461)

It's not clear to me from reading the comments on any of these issues whether the problem resides in WSL1 or in the toolchain used to create the `gzip` binary.  In the Eoan case, the issue was ultimately "resolved" in `binutils`, but it's not clear to me if that was just a workaround for what was really a WSL1 issue at the core.

In any case, there are three possible solutions:

- If you can, run Jammy under WSL2.  The Linux kernel in WSL2 handles the changes to `gzip` without issue.  It's just a problem in the WSL1 ELF loader.
- Use the workaround above to replace `gzip` with a version earlier on the path that calls the "real" (but broken) version through `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`.
- From [a comment](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8219#issuecomment-1110508016) in the WSL GitHub issue, it's possible to patch the `gzip` binary to resolve the issue.  I'm not a personal fan of this approach, but if you would like to try it:

```
echo -en '\x10' | sudo dd of=/usr/bin/gzip count=1 bs=1 conv=notrunc seek=$((0x189))
```

Since something in the toolchain is likely the culprit, this issue also seems to be showing up in:

- Other distributions (reportedly Arch and almost certainly others)
- Other binaries (reportedly Node.js)

There is reportedly a patch for the Node issue as well in that GitHub thread.

Patching distribution binaries, however, is not without risk.  Hopefully someone will either identify the toolchain issue that is causing this or the WSL team will change the ELF loader code to compensate.

Answer (score 0):

To make the Ubuntu-22.04 WSL 1 have a working version of gzip 1.10-4ubuntu4,
you could change the value at offset 0x189 with the following command:

```
echo -en '\x10' | sudo dd of=/usr/bin/gzip count=1 bs=1 conv=notrunc seek=$((0x189))
```

Comment: Isn't that exactly the same command I suggested in my answer from two months ago? ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Change WSL 1 to WSL 2 worked for me

https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/wsl/#enabling-docker-support-in-wsl-2-distros

Get the list of distro names:

```
wsl -l -v
```

Change WSL version :

```
wsl --set-version <DISTRO NAME> 2
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to AskUbuntu! While you describe a solution that may have worked for you, upgrading an entire software package is not always the best solution. Also, your answer describes how to upgrade from WSL1 to WSL2 rather than addressing the issue at hand itself.

Comment: @JohnRed thanks for your advice!